# Menu Editor in Wordpress WP-ADMIN generating error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting the following error when I open the menu editor in the admin options.

[image]

The site is on a IIS web server and it's currently using php v5.6.0

So far I have tried the following approaches:

- adding define(CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false) tag in the wp-config file.
- changing the php version on the IIS from 5.6.0 to 7.1.21

I have less than a months working with wordpress and I had never used php before.

--------------------- EDIT ---------------------

It seems the issue might be related to permissions because when I try to access the javascript file which is not missing from the js folder I get the following message:

[image]

This is the only file in the folder which I cannot access. I also checked the permissions of the file in the server and it has the same as the other files.

Comment: Have you tried to clear your browser's cached files?

Answer (score 0):

First:
You should post the code which you are using, if you are not using any code, the paste proper screenshots here.
Second:
Its a syntax error which means there's a mistake in your code. So you need to check the code, there's an extra "<" somewhere in the code.

Comment: "Unexpected token <" usually happens when you're using a file that doesn't exist